# null pointer exception while implementing list in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android

I want to display a simple list using actionbar sherlock fragment. The below code is part of a progam which will get executed when the user click a tab. The code worked fine when used in a acitivity.And Ignore the json part.

```
    Code for FragmentTab2.java
package com.androidbegin.absviewpagertutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class FragmentTab2 extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
        return super.getSherlockActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab2.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);

         initList();
            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(FragmentTab2.this.getActivity(), employeeList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"employees"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
            listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);




        //Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab2.this.getActivity(), Favourites.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

     List<Map<String,String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
private void initList(){

        /* Intent intent = getIntent();
          final String result = intent.getExtras().getString("newresult");//final so that variable can be used in onclick method
            try{
               // returnString = "";
             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String name=json_data.getString("name");
                String department=json_data.getString("department");
                String role=json_data.getString("role");
                String designation=json_data.getString("designation");
                String email=json_data.getString("email");
                String interest=json_data.getString("interest");
                String photos=json_data.getString("photos");
                String outPut = name + "-" +department + "-" +role + "-" +designation +"-" +email +"-" +interest +"-" +photos;
                employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));

          }}
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }*/

    String name="ram";
    String department="sdf";
    String role="sfdag";
    String designation="fsdg";
    String email="gsad";
    String interest="ahgs";
    String photos="gsa";
    String outPut = name + "-" +department + "-" +role + "-" +designation +"-" +email +"-" +interest +"-" +photos;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));





            ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                /*  try{
                        //passing jsondata to result page
                     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject((int) id);
                     Intent obj_intent = new Intent(AdvancedSearch.this, Result.class);
                     Bundle b = new Bundle();  
                     b.putString("jsonobject",json_data.toString());
                        obj_intent.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(obj_intent);
                    }
                      catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }*/





                }

            });


     }

     private HashMap<String, String>createEmployee(String name,String department){
      HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
      employeeNameNo.put(name,department);
      return employeeNameNo;
     }



}
    logcat:
01-11 10:51:20.641: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onHoverEvent
01-11 10:51:20.641: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4293: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-11 10:51:20.652: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-11 10:51:20.652: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-11 10:51:20.681: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getAlpha
01-11 10:51:20.681: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3039: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:20.681: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:20.681: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:20.681: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getTranslationY
01-11 10:51:20.681: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3040: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
01-11 10:51:20.681: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:20.681: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
01-11 10:51:20.691: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setAlpha
01-11 10:51:20.691: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3043: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.691: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:20.691: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.691: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setTranslationY
01-11 10:51:20.691: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3050: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.691: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:20.691: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.791: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
01-11 10:51:20.791: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 296: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-11 10:51:20.791: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01d1
01-11 10:51:20.791: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
01-11 10:51:20.791: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 292: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-11 10:51:20.791: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01df
01-11 10:51:20.821: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x01d4-01d8 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
01-11 10:51:20.821: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x01e2-01e8 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
01-11 10:51:20.931: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getAlpha
01-11 10:51:20.931: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2796: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:20.931: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:20.931: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:20.941: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationX
01-11 10:51:20.941: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2801: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
01-11 10:51:20.941: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:20.941: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
01-11 10:51:20.941: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationY
01-11 10:51:20.941: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2802: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
01-11 10:51:20.941: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:20.941: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
01-11 10:51:20.967: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setAlpha
01-11 10:51:20.967: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2817: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.971: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:20.971: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.971: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationX
01-11 10:51:20.971: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2821: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.993: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:20.993: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.993: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationY
01-11 10:51:20.993: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2822: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-11 10:51:20.993: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:20.993: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.041: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.dispatchHoverEvent
01-11 10:51:21.053: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5154: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-11 10:51:21.053: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
01-11 10:51:21.053: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.dispatchHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-11 10:51:21.053: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
01-11 10:51:21.053: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3042: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
01-11 10:51:21.061: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
01-11 10:51:21.171: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineHorizontalScrollView.getAlpha
01-11 10:51:21.171: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3053: Landroid/widget/HorizontalScrollView;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:21.171: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:21.181: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineHorizontalScrollView;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:21.181: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineHorizontalScrollView.setAlpha
01-11 10:51:21.181: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3054: Landroid/widget/HorizontalScrollView;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.181: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:21.181: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineHorizontalScrollView;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.221: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.getAlpha
01-11 10:51:21.221: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3093: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:21.221: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:21.221: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
01-11 10:51:21.221: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.getTranslationX
01-11 10:51:21.221: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3096: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
01-11 10:51:21.221: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-11 10:51:21.221: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
01-11 10:51:21.221: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setAlpha
01-11 10:51:21.221: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3108: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.221: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:21.231: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.231: I/dalvikvm(362): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setTranslationX
01-11 10:51:21.231: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3114: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.241: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-11 10:51:21.241: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
01-11 10:51:21.341: D/dalvikvm(362): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
01-11 10:51:21.341: W/dalvikvm(362): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3037 (ROOT) in Ljava/util/Locale;
01-11 10:51:21.341: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
01-11 10:51:21.352: D/dalvikvm(362): VFY: dead code 0x0014-001a in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/CapitalizingTextView;.setTextCompat (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
01-11 10:51:21.571: D/AndroidRuntime(362): Shutting down VM
01-11 10:51:21.571: W/dalvikvm(362): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-11 10:51:21.681: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3374 objects / 253840 bytes in 93ms
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.androidbegin.absviewpagertutorial.FragmentTab2.initList(FragmentTab2.java:103)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.androidbegin.absviewpagertutorial.FragmentTab2.onCreateView(FragmentTab2.java:44)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:696)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-11 10:51:21.681: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash.

Comment: i am getting a null pointer exception. Check out the logcat. I posted it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Change your `ListView lv;` as **Global** initilize the `ListView` before calling the function.

```
 ListView lv;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab2.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);


         lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         initList();
            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(FragmentTab2.this.getActivity(), employeeList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"employees"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
            lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);




        //Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab2.this.getActivity(), Favourites.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        return view;
    }
```

and inside `initList()` function reomve `ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

Comment: thnx mate. This resolved the null pointer exception. But now I am getting a class cast exception.

Comment: logcat:01-11 11:05:16.681: E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 11:05:16.681: E/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
01-11 11:05:16.681: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.androidbegin.absviewpagertutorial.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:112)
01-11 11:05:16.681: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
01-11 11:05:16.681: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)

Comment: @DikshayPoojary what is the line number 112 in `MainActiv‌​ity.java`

Comment: It was a public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {} function. I just removed it and got the program working.

Answer (score 0):

for Fragments, `getView()` method returns `null` until `onCreateView()` method is returned. and in `onCreateView()` method, you are calling `initList()` in which you are calling `getView()` method which returns `null`.

try passing `ListView` as parameter to `initList()`... I trimmed your code a little bit...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab2.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    initList(listView);
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            FragmentTab2.this.getActivity(), employeeList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    // Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab2.this.getActivity(),
    // Favourites.class);
    // startActivity(intent);
    return view;
}

private void initList(ListView listView) {
    String name = "ram";
    String department = "sdf";
    String role = "sfdag";
    String designation = "fsdg";
    String email = "gsad";
    String interest = "ahgs";
    String photos = "gsa";
    String outPut = name + "-" + department + "-" + role + "-"
            + designation + "-" + email + "-" + interest + "-" + photos;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }

    });
}
```